# zip file not created

Tags: c#, c#-ziparchive

I tried below code to first convert my `bytes` to `compressed bytes` and try to create a `zip` file, but file is not generated. Could someone please suggest!

```
byte[] result;
var X = 86251;
byte[] compressedBytes;

using (FileStream SourceStream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open))
{
    SourceStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    result = new byte[X];

    await SourceStream.ReadAsync(result, 0, X);
}

string fileName = "Export_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss") + ".zip";
using (var outStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var archive = new ZipArchive(outStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    {
        var fileInArchive = archive.CreateEntry(fileName, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
        using (var entryStream = fileInArchive.Open())
        using (var fileToCompressStream = new MemoryStream(result))
        {
            fileToCompressStream.CopyTo(entryStream);
        }
    }
    compressedBytes = outStream.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: You're writing the archive to a MemoryStream and then converting it into a byte array `compressedBytes `. There is no evidence of you writing it to a file.

Comment: `string fileName = "Export_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss") + ".zip";`

Comment: Yep, I saw that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not creating an actual file anywhere. You're just writing to a memory stream. Change it to write to a file.

```
using (var outStream = new File.Create(fileName))
{
    using (var archive = new ZipArchive(outStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    {
        var fileInArchive = archive.CreateEntry(filename, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
        using (var entryStream = fileInArchive.Open())
        using (var fileToCompressStream = new MemoryStream(result))
        {
            fileToCompressStream.CopyTo(entryStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, zip file is created, but when unzip, I m seeing one more zip file and when tries to open, it's says corrupt

Comment: @user The file created with `CreateEntry` is the contents of `result` - you ought to give it a different name to the parent zip file. I've changed it to `filename` above. You should change `filename` or `fileName` to be a different name as I didn't immediately realise that these were different variables.